# Free array of pointers in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc, free

I work on an eclipse environment with C. To explain things simply I have a simple struct to define some elements needed in my project :

```
typedef struct adc adc_def;

     struct adc {
        SPI_HandleTypeDef *spi_hal;
        //Adresse de l'esclave avec qui communiquer
        uint8_t numero_adc;
        registres_adc config;

    };
```

I also have a function instantiating a new struct (the one declared previously). I need 4 of them, that I store in a global array:

```
adc_def* adc_new(SPI_HandleTypeDef *param_spi_hal, uint8_t numero_adc) {

    adc_def *adc = NULL;

    registres_adc tmp_config;

    adc_status_t status_adc;

    if ((NULL != param_spi_hal) && numero_adc <= ADC_MAX) {
        if (NULL != (adc = malloc(sizeof(adc_def)))) {


            adc->spi_hal = param_spi_hal;
            adc->numero_adc = numero_adc;

            adc->config.configuration = DEFAULT_CONF;

            //Copie des tab en const pour les passer dans la fonction
            memcpy(adc->config.hpf, HPF, 2);
            memcpy(adc->config.fsc, FSC, 3);
            memcpy(adc->config.ofc, OFC, 3);

            if (HAL_OK != adc_stopCont(adc)) {
                free(adc);
                adc = NULL;
            }
            ///////////
            if (HAL_OK != adc_setConfig(adc, adc->config)) {
                free(adc);
                adc = NULL;

            }

        }
    }
    return adc;
}
```

Once I'm in my main program I store 4 of them in a global array :

```
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;
adc_def *adc_present[4];


void re_init(){

    for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
        free(adc_present[z]);
        adc_present[z] = NULL;
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
        adc_present[a] = adc_new(&hspi1, a+1);
    }

}

int main(void) {

    for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
        adc_present[a] = adc_new(&hspi1, a+1);

    }

    re_init();

}
```

In my program I will need to free all the struct stored in adc_present to, again, recreate other adc_def struct elements. Therefore I do this code for that :

It seems like this code provoke memory leaks and bugs, I cannot reaffect in this tab even though I used free previously. Am I missing something? The tab is not being freed correctly here?
I have an array of pointers allocated dynamically that I free before reaffecting them, I don't understand

Comment: Is this your real code? I don't think `adc_present[a] = *adc_new(&hspi1, a+1);` will compile.

Comment: I guess you meant `adc_present[a] = adc_new(&hspi1, a+1);`?

Comment: Please assemble your code fragements to provide a [mre] which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: In `adc_new()`, `adc` could be null on this line: `if (HAL_OK != adc_setConfig(adc, adc->config)) {`.

Comment: @MikeCat yes you pointed a mistak I made, it was a mistake I did while copying my code. I edited my question with the real code

Comment: @Yunnosch what I meant was that I can't free the elements in my array, to have other elements there. 
Whenever I compile this code, it works, but there are some memory leaks appearing making the whole program bug

Answer (score 0):

One problem is in this code:

```
        if (HAL_OK != adc_stopCont(adc)) {
            free(adc);
            adc = NULL;
        }
        ///////////
        if (HAL_OK != adc_setConfig(adc, adc->config)) {
            free(adc);
            adc = NULL;

        }
```

If the call to `adc_stopCont()` fails, you set `adc` to `NULL` with

```
            adc = NULL;
```

but then call `adc_setConfig()` anyway:

```
        if (HAL_OK != adc_setConfig(adc, adc->config)) {
```

If `adc` is `NULL`, that will fail because `adc->config` will try to dereference a `NULL` pointer.

This would be much better:

```
        if (HAL_OK != adc_stopCont(adc)) {
            free(adc);
            adc = NULL;
        }
        else if (HAL_OK != adc_setConfig(adc, adc->config)) {
            free(adc);
            adc = NULL;
        }
```

or

```
        if (HAL_OK != adc_stopCont(adc)) {
            free(adc);
            return(NULL);
        }
        if (HAL_OK != adc_setConfig(adc, adc->config)) {
            free(adc);
            return(NULL);
        }
```